# TS2409: Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i Am having a problem in typeScript + angular ,  here class foo is a service which is using another service as fooService and fooServie.getUser() is returning a promise of some type

compilation is good but with this type error :TS2409: Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class

Pleae help me out with the issue

```
module fooModule {

    export class foo {

        static $inject = ['fooService'];

        constructor(public fooService:services.fooService) {

            return fooService.getUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> compilation is good but with this type error :TS2409: Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class

The error is very clear. The return statement from the constructor `return fooService.getUser();` should give an instance of the class `class foo`. e.g.

```
declare class FooService{
    getfoo():foo;
}

class foo {

    constructor(public fooService:FooService) {
        return fooService.getfoo();
    }
}
```

Otherwise in `var f = new foo` the variable `f` would not be of type `foo`.

### Update

I am not sure what you intent is but hopefully this will guide you more:

```
module fooModule {

    export class Foo {

        static $inject = ['fooService'];

        constructor(public fooService:services.FooService) {
        }
        
        getUser():ng.IPromise<User>{
            return this.fooService.getUser();
        }
    }
    
    var foo = new Foo(); 
    foo.getUser().then(()=>{
        // complete this code here 
    });
}
```

Comment: but i cannot keep getfoo of type foo i my scenario getfoo is returning ng.IPromise<someType>

Comment: var foo = new Foo();  line would expect and argument as the constructor expects and to be more clear i am going to use the foo class in resolve of ui-router as resolve:{user:foo}